# How to fill the table with the correct number of rows to fit the page height in different screen resolution ?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I developed my own Web-Admin behind the front-end. It's a typical Admin with container , one menu-navigation   in the left and a body content  in the right which shows the result (typically a table) related to the clicked menu item.

What is the best way to get the correct number or rows in the table in order to fit the the body page at 100% ?

In my case, i have seen that the number of tow required to fill the space in the table is different while changing the screen resolution.

I know a quick solution could be to calculate the resolution and get the table populated after knowing the screen resolution. I was wondering if if possible to set the TD or TR height at runtime, based on the screen resolution or somehow else.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdN5z/) that demonstrates the rendering of rows depending on the browser innerHeight.

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable"></table>​
```

**CSS**

```
td {
  height:20px;
}​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var numberOfRows = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 20);

var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

function createCell() {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerText = "Cell";
    return cell;
}

function createRow() {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.appendChild(createCell())
    return row;
}

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    table.appendChild(createRow());
}​
```

**PS. 1** I've set the height of the cell in CSS, this can be done differently
**PS. 2** I've floored the number of rows that fit on the screen. So there will be some empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Hey Bart, that worked like a charm :)

May I ask if is possible to do also the opposite ? Lets say i need to have just 20 rows each page (as i have pagination) and want to fit the screen with the same number of rows in each screen-resolution. I mean . .how adjust the TD height to fill the page ? It will also help myself in another thing .. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure! Here is a fiddle doing that: http://jsfiddle.net/MdN5z/1/ Please approve my answer if you're happy! :-)

Comment: more than happy. Thanks (answer should be approved - sorry first time here in stackoverflow )

Comment: @user1611183 (It is not yet approved ;-))

Comment: dont get me wrong :) how can i approve ? just checked all link in the page but there is no "approve" button ..